# C# If lastbutton tag equals currently clicked button, disable both

Tags: c#, button

I'm creating a matching game. What I'm trying to accomplish is a check that will see if the tag of the previously clicked button, matches the tag of the "currently" clicked button. If those tags match, it would disable both the buttons as they are no longer an option in the game.
Part of my confusion is where to integrate this portion of code without screwing up the majority of my work.

```
Random myRandom = new Random();
    var buttons = new List<Button> { button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12 };
    var carString = new List<string> { "Camaro", "Mini Cooper", "Porsche 944", "Ford Focus", "Chevy Blazer", "Model T", "Camaro", "Mini Cooper", "Porsche 944", "Ford Focus", "Chevy Blazer", "Model T" };
    while (matchingButtonIndex < numOfButtons)
        {
            int index = myRandom.Next(carString.Count);
            var name = carString[index];
            if (name != null)
        {
        buttons[matchingButtonIndex].Tag = name;
        carString[index] = null;
        matchingButtonIndex = matchingButtonIndex + 1;
     }
   }
 }
    void SwitchTagWithText()
    {
        string text = lastButton.Text;
        lastButton.Text = lastButton.Tag.ToString();
        lastButton.Tag = text;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastButton != null)
        {
            SwitchTagWithText();
        }

        lastButton = sender as Button;
        SwitchTagWithText();

        buttoncount++;
        label2.Text = buttoncount.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I think the method declaration was omitted from your first method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a new class to handle this e.g.

```
public class ButtonManager {
    private Button lastButton;

    public void SwitchTagWithText(Button button){
        string text = lastButton.Text;
        lastButton.Text = lastButton.Tag.ToString();
        lastButton.Tag = text;

        // Or whatever the logic is you need.
    }

    public void ButtonClicked(Button button){
        this.SwitchTagWithText(button);
        // Or whatever the logic is you need.
    }
}
```

OK the above is incomplete, but hopefully the main idea comes through - that you have a separate class to deal with the reading/setting of tag values and determining whether buttons should be disabled.

So in your from load, create a new instance of `ButtonManager` that can be used throughout the form's code, so make it a field.

Answer (score 0):

You have a button count variable which you are incrementing with each click. So you can use that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thisButton = sender as Button;

    buttoncount++;

    SwitchTagWithText(thisButton);

    if (buttoncount == 1)
    {
        lastButton = thisButton;
    }
    else if (buttoncount == 2)
    {
        if (lastButton.Tag == thisButton.tag)
        {
            // Disable both buttons.
        }
        else
        {
            // Switch buttons back
        }

        buttoncount = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastButton != null)
        {
            SwitchTagWithText();
            var thisButton = sender as Button;
            if(thisButton.Text != lastButton.Text 
                 && thisButton.Tag.ToString() == lastButton.Tag.ToString())
            {
                //two different buttons with the same tag were clicked in succession
                thisButton.Enabled = false;
                lastButton.Enabled = false;
                lastButton = null;
                return;
            }
            lastButton = thisButton;
        }
        else
        {
           lastButton = sender as Button;
        }

        SwitchTagWithText();

        buttoncount++;
        label2.Text = buttoncount.ToString();
    }
```